# Почему массив не сортируется?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int dig[10];
    int i, j, max_index, tmp;
    srand (time(NULL));

    for (i = 0 ; i <= 9 ; i++) {
        /*Заполняем случайными числами*/
        dig[i] = 0 + rand() %21;
        printf("%d ",dig[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    /*Сортировка по возрастанию*/
    for (i = 9; i <= 0; i--) {
        max_index = 0;
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if(dig[j] >= dig[max_index])
                max_index = j;
            tmp = dig[i];
            dig[i] = dig[max_index];
            dig[max_index] = tmp;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        printf("%d ",dig[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Почему выводит ту же самую последовательность? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`for ( i = 9 ; i <= 0 ; i--)` — сколько раз выполнится цикл? :-)